# Do the units in this equation make any sense?

Tags: friction, dimensional-analysis, oscillators

I've recently asked a question regarding the function
$$x(t)=A_0e^{-\frac{b}{2m} t} \cos{(\omega t+\varphi)}.$$
It is a solution to the damped pendulum equation. I found it [here](https://opentextbc.ca/universityphysicsv1openstax/chapter/15-5-damped-oscillations/), where $A_0$ is the initial angular displacement of the pendulum, $b$ is the damping constant, $m$ is the mass of the pendulum, $\omega$ is the natural angular frequency of the damped pendulum and $\varphi$ is the phase of the function.

My question is, how do the units "add-up" here? I know $x(t)$ should return an angular displacement given time. But, I am confused as to how the unit in the exponential factor would affect the unit of the result. I've read from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316131/) that units in the exponent don't make sense, which furthers my confusion.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: The units in the exponent do make sense. $(-b/2m)t$ is dimensionless. Start from the equation of motion: $m$ = force/acceleration, $b$ = force/velocity, $b/m$ = acceleration/velocity = 1/time, $(b/m)t$ = dimensionless.

Comment: An exponent cannot have a unit. It is by definition the number of repeated multiplications of the base number by itself. It doesn't make much sense to multiply $e$ by itself "1 metre times" or something like that.

Comment: @alephzero why would $b=force/velocity$? I am aware that it is a dimensionless ratio.

Comment: @SeanXie, "b" has any units that simplify to "m/t", because that is what is required to keep the whole exponent dimensionless.  And note, "ma/at" does in fact simplify to "m/t", where ma=F and at=v.

Comment: @SeanXie just by inspecting the original differentual equation $m\ddot{x} + b \dot{x} + k x = 0$, each term has to be in units of Force since it's just newton's second law. So the coefficient of the velocity term, b, must have units of Force per velocity.

Comment: That solution applies *specifically* to the spring-mass damped oscillator. It doesn't apply to the pendulum, so the $b/2m$ term is incorrect.

Comment: @BillN Does the solution to a damped pendulum equation exist as one does for a spring-mass system? If both systems are damped oscillators, why does one not apply to the other? I'm not too experienced in physics so any information is appreciated!

Comment: A closed form (equation) approximate solution exists for small amplitude oscillations. That solution is sinusoidal, but the frequency $\omega$ depends on $g$ and the length of the string, not on some $k$, spring constant. The spring frequency is independent of $g$. The damping term for the pendulum depends on the length of the string. The damping term for the spring-mass is length independent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An exponent cannot have a unit. It is by definition (unless you redefine it for a particular context) the number of repeated multiplications of the base number by itself. It doesn't make much sense to multiply $e$ by itself "1 metre times" or something like that.

It *must* be a unitless number. If it isn't, then you are missing a correction factor. It is possible when constructing  empiric relationships to end up with units in the exponent, but then a parameter ought to be introduced to "cancel out" the unit so that it is mathematically sound. If it isn't, then it's mathematically sloppy - then it has just been left our for convenience. Regardless, the unit in an exponent has no meaning and shouldn't be there.

Comment: "An exponent cannot have a unit." See my comment on another answer.

Comment: @philipxy Right, you are referring to redefining a function with an exponent in cases where a new definition is sensible. Sure, this is possible. If such redefinition is not mentioned in a particular context, though, then I'd argue that we can only assume the usual definition by default. Just like we can only assume usual definitions of any other arithmetic symbols and methods (such as $+$ and $-$) if we aren't explicitly informed otherwise. With the original definition of the exponent, which surely applies in this case, an exponent is indeed unitless.

Comment: This is definition of exponents is only correct for positive integers and is not the general definition of exponentiation.  And cases where exponents have units are not “redefinitions” of exponents, but formally “applications” of them (a term which applies to all uses of mathematics in physics).  For instance, there are many physical cases where exponents properly have angular units.

Comment: Nothing is stopping anyone from using a non-dimensionless expression as an exponent. Upon which you have been "explicitly informed".

Comment: @philipxy: What are the units of $e^{1m}$?

Comment: @RBarryYoung In physics, an angular unit - the SI unit *radian* - is also actually "unitless", since it is defined as a ratio.

Answer (score 7):

As the post you've linked says, any argument of functions such as $\cos$ and $\exp$ must be dimensionless. That is to say, $bt/m$ is dimensionless, as are $\omega t$ and $\varphi$. These parts of the function cannot affect the units of the result.

The dimension of $x(t)$ comes from $A_0$, which has dimensions of 'angle' (which is really dimensionless).

Comment: It is not the case that an exponent must be dimensionless. Clearly we allow arguments & results of some function applications to have dimensions, like negation, division, product & sum. People are just used to certain common patterns of dimensions & operators. We can express a dimension d quantity as exp(f) where f has dimension ln d. What is the case in the question is that the exponent happens to be dimensionless.

Comment: @philipxy If $x$ is some quantity with numeric value $x_n$ when written in units/with dimensions $x_d$ then $x=x_nx_d$. So if $x=e^f$ then $f=\ln x_n+\ln x_d,$ which looks like the *sum* of a dimensionless value and a dimensioned one, not the product a dimensioned value is "supposed" to be. Down this road there seems to only be pain...

Comment: idk how you can say "$A_0$ has dimensions of angle" and also say "the argument to cos must be dimensionless". Either angle is a dimension or it isn't.

Comment: @philipxy - the problem with your idea is that by their nature logarithms can produce only dimensionless output, so $\ln d$ is dimensionless. The logarithm is defined by $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac {dt}t$. Because $dt$ has the same dimensions as $t$, it does not matter what dimensions are given to $t$ (and its specific values of $1$ and $x$), the result is a sum of the dimensionless ratio $\frac{dt}t$, and is thus dimensionless itself.

Comment: @PaulSinclair That is like saying that "by their nature" sum & product are dimensionless.Things are being claimed on this page about dimensional analysis that are simply not true.

Comment: @HTNW Your example doesn't make sense, units/dimensions aren't values & juxtaposition of value & unit/dimension denote not product but a dimensioned value. Maybe you mean something like, for x as quantity n along dimension d, suppose x = nd = n*1d & x = exp(f). Then f = ln(nd) = (ln(n))lnd = ln(n*1d) = ln(n)+1lnd. So what? (Rhetorical.) There's more to dimensional analysis than the 4 arithmetic operators. (Beware of 'supposed' & of scare quotes.) I'd agree we can write expressions with ambiguous subexpression dimensions. But then we could explicitly give the dimension of ambiguous calls.

Comment: @user253751 good clarification, i've edited my answer

Comment: @philipxy Note the difference between units and dimensions. In HTNW's comment, $x_d$ is a unit, not a dimension. The problem with expressions like $\ln x_d$ is that they are not well defined. For example, consider the expressions $\ln\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$ and $\ln c$; what values should they have? They cannot both be zero, because they must have different values, because $\ln\frac{c}{\mathrm{m/s}}=\ln299792458\ne0$.

Comment: @philipxy - say what?? I did not just claim "it was unitless by its nature". Instead that was an introductory sentence, which I followed by explaining exactly *why* the logarithm produces dimensionless results. The explanation does not in any way apply to sums or products. Unlike you, I have backed up my claim with a full argument, which you ignored to make a senseless reply.

Answer (score 4):

The function $\exp(x)$  is usually define as dimensionless and it is define only for dimensionless number $x$. In your case,  $−b\cdot t/2m$ is dimensionless and so is $e^{−b\cdot t/2m}$. Similarly, $ωt+φ$ and $\cos(ωt+φ)$ are dimensionless.

In conulsion, you get that the units of $x(t)$ are just the same units as the units of $A_0$.

Answer (score 3):

A pendulum doesn't use exactly the same quantities as the link you posted. *Don't use an equation without examining its context and limitations!*

Examining the traditional damped HO differential equation for a simple pendulum with small angle approximation:
$$m r^2\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{ dt}^2}+\frac{b}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{dt}}+mgrx=0$$
we see that $b$ must have units of torque$\times$ time / displacement.

In your situation, your displacement is radians (angular displacement), so the SI units of $b$ are newton-meter--seconds per radian.

In your exponent you have $\frac{bt}{2m}$ and the units would be newton$\cdot$meter$\cdot$seconds$^2$ per radian or meter$^2$. That's obviously incorrect.

I believe you've simply adopted some standard form equation with adapting it to a rotational (torque) situation. Consider that you need to use moment of inertia ($mr^2$) of the pendulum rather than the mass.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is the units of $b$. The requirement that the input to the exponential is dimensionless *implies* that, together with the form of the exponent,

$$[b] = [MT^{-1}]$$

since $[\frac{t}{m}] = [TM^{-1}]$. So the damping constant has units of mass flow rate (e.g. kilograms or grams per second), and that cancels the units of $t$ and $m$ and leaves a dimensionless exponent.